# In ASP.NET Web API Core, how can I force a 401 response

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using OAuth2 and OIDC in my ASP.NET Core Web API Service.  When I get a JWT token in, it validates it.

In my case, my Issuer is not matching.  I am able to see this because the results of the validation are surfaced in the `JwtBearerEvents` event  `OnAuthenticationFailed`.  That is the point where I can know that I need to return 401.

**How can I set my service to return 401 at that point?**

Comment: Are you using IdentityServer4 for OAuth2 and OIDC management? I might have a solution around this if your are

Comment: @IsmailUmar - Unfortunately no.  I am using WSO2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't had a chance to test this in a real project, but if you just want to return a 401, then you might want to try something like:

```
OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = 401; 
    context.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized").Wait();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```